# How to pass a mock to unitundertest with jMockit?

Tags: junit, jmockit

I want to pass a Mock to my unitUnderTest. How can I achieve this in JMockit?
See the following code excerpt.

```
@Test
public void paymentResponseCreatorTest(){
    final ClassUnderTest unitUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

    MockUp<JSONObject> mockup = new MockUp<JSONObject>(){
        private final Map<String, JSONValue> map = new HashMap<>();

        @Mock
        public JSONValue put(String key, JSONValue jsonValue){
            map.put(key, jsonValue);
            return jsonValue;
        }
        @Mock
        public JSONValue get(String key){
            return map.get(key);
        }
    };


    JSONObject jsonObject = mockup.getMockInstance();
    jsonObject.put("Status", new JSONString("Y"));
    jsonObject.put("a", new JSONString("123"));
    jsonObject.put("b", new JSONString("123"));

    unitUnderTest.newInstance(jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: You can use the `@Tested` and `@Injectable` annotations. But I can't tell for sure what's more appropriate, without knowing which object needs to be passed into `ClassUnderTest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Deencapsulation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Deencapsulation.html) as follows:

```
    Deencapsulation.setField(referenceOfUnitUnderTest, referenceOfMockedOrRealInstance);
```